# Getting error The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#

I am getting this compile error error: *"The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"*

Below is my code:

```
static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static Collection<T> ToCollection(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        Collection<T> sourceCollection = new Collection<T>();

        foreach (T currentSourceInstance in source)
        {
            sourceCollection.Add(currentSourceInstance);
        }

        return sourceCollection;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static Collection<T> ToCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        Collection<T> sourceCollection = new Collection<T>();

        foreach (T currentSourceInstance in source)
        {
            sourceCollection.Add(currentSourceInstance);
        }

        return sourceCollection;
    }
}
```

Notice the `ToCollection<T>`, otherwise the compiler doesn't understand where this `T` is coming from.

You can call it like this (where `Thing` is your custom type in this example):

```
var items = new List<Thing>();
var collection = items.ToCollection<Thing>();
```